# NLog setup for .NET5 worker service template

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, nlog

I am trying to get NLog working in a .NET5 worker service template for a while now. But whatever I try there are no logs at all. Unfortunatly nor the website, github or google brought me any clues why.

I using

- the .NET5 worker service template
- NLog.Extensions.Logging version 1.7.4

Just to make sure, the target directory for the log file is created upfront.

The appsettings.json used:

```
{
  "NLog": {
    "throwConfigExceptions": true,
    "targets": {
      "async": true,
      "logfile": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "c:/temp/nlog/nlog-${shortdate}.log"
      },
      "logconsole": {
        "type": "Console"
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Info",
        "writeTo": "logconsole"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Debug",
        "writeTo": "logfile"
      }
    ]
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

The full code of the setup (all still the basic templates) but something must be missing:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NLogSample
{

    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, logging) => 
                {
                    // ensure just use NLog
                    logging.Services.Clear(); 
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
 
                    //logging.AddNLog(hostContext.Configuration);
                    logging.AddNLog(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("NLog"));
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                })
                //.UseNLog()
                ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `logging.AddNLog(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("NLog"));` with `logging.AddNLog(hostContext.Configuration, new NLog.Extensions.Logging.NLogProviderOptions() { LoggingConfigurationSectionName = "NLog" });`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/67780779/193178

Comment: that raises an exception that ILogger can not be injected into the Worker

Comment: You should replace `logging.Services.Clear();` with `logging.ClearProviders();`

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying `LoggingConfigurationSectionName = "NLog"` and replace `logging.Services.Clear()` with `logging.ClearProviders()`. Like this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, logging) => 
        {
            // ensure just use NLog
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
            logging.AddNLog(hostContext.Configuration, new NLogProviderOptions() { LoggingConfigurationSectionName = "NLog" });
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67780779/193178